# How can I preserve the brightness settings of my laptop display on standby?

Tags: suspend, brightness, thinkpad

I use a Lenovo Thinkpad X230. Occasionally it occurs that the brightness is being reduced to a much lower value on resume from suspend.

I would like to preserve the brightness setting as set by `Fn + F8/F9`.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Classical way to approach this issue would be to create `/etc/pm/sleep.d/10_remember_brightness` script with the following contents. Note, that the script must be made executable (via `chmod +x` command) and must be owned by root.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Description: remember backlight brightness before suspending

case "${1}" in

        hibernate|sleep) before_suspend=$(cat /sys/class/backlight/*/brightness )
    ;;
        resume|thaw) echo "$before_suspend" > /sys/class/backlight/*/brightness
    ;;
esac
```

---

If the script doesn't always catch up and restore brightness, use `sleep` delay as shown below ( `sleep` value given in seconds, 0.25 is quarter-second, adjust as necessary )

```
#!/bin/bash
# Description: remember backlight brightness before suspending

case "${1}" in

        hibernate|sleep) before_suspend=$(cat /sys/class/backlight/*/brightness )
    ;;
        resume|thaw) sleep 0.25 && echo "$before_suspend" > /sys/class/backlight/*/brightness
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: One question Serg. The script does not always work. Could it be that I need to add `sleep` to let the script wait for a couple of seconds before running on resume from suspend?

Comment: @orschiro  Yes, you can add delay for it.  I'l add that to the answer